# shopping cart discount rule only applying to specific products

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart, discount

I have a shopping cart rule that applies 15% discount if customer has $500 or more of a specific category of products in cart. It's working fine, but how do I only apply the 15% to that category total and not entire cart total?

For example the cart rule is 15% discount on all tires and total over $500.

Shopping cart:

X Tires - $650

Gift card - $300

Rims - $1200

**Total - $2150**

The discount should be $97.50 not $322.50

Comment: In action tab of the shopping cart rule set the category id

Comment: How to new rule like  ....applies 15% discount if customer has $500 or more of a specific category of products in cart?@Alen Giliana

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look on following rule. You have create a rule on item base not for whole cart base.

[image]

This will apply a 15% discount to only products which are belongs to category 3 only.

Have a look on output. Hope this will help you.
[image]

Comment: If I wanted to add free shipping to the coupon action but only for select coutries, how would I accomplish? I tried adding it to the condition, but it was requiring the country to be added before the code is applied. http://prntscr.com/b4w6hw

Comment: @ Ashish Madankar : my discount amount is lesser than what i gave, actually i set 15 % discount.  70rs 15 % is 10.5 but my value is 7.5. how can i  solve this error.

Comment: @ Ashish Madankar : One of my category consists all are grouped products,  when i applied what you told, tha discount amount not applied properly.